# Get a different (non default) widget when using param in parameterized class (holoviz param panel)

Tags: python, holoviz, panel-pyviz, param-pyviz

I use a parameterized class to build my Panel dashboard.

I would like to use a [CrossSelector](https://panel.pyviz.org/reference/widgets/CrossSelector.html#gallery-crossselector) but this selector does not seem to be available when looking at the options that library Param gives. It only seems to have a [ListSelector](https://param.pyviz.org/Reference_Manual/param.html).

How do i get this CrossSelector using Param?

```
import param
import panel as pn

pn.extension()

class ValveExplorer(param.Parameterized):

    selected_features = param.ListSelector(
        default=[1, 3],
        objects=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    )

valve_explorer = ValveExplorer()  

# show list selector
pn.Row(valve_explorer.param['selected_features'])
```

This results in the following default ListSelector but I don't want this one. I would like to get a CrossSelector instead:
[image: default multiselect used by param]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Param has a default widget for every Selector, but you can change this.

You can override this default widget as follows to get the CrossSelector in your example by using **pn.Param()**:

```
pn.Row(pn.Param(
    valve_explorer.param['selected_features'], 
    widgets={'selected_features': pn.widgets.CrossSelector}
))
```

A [similar solution found on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911674/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-the-widget-type-in-an-hvplot-holoviews-panel-obje) is using pn.panel():

```
pn.Row(pn.panel(
    valve_explorer.param['selected_features'], 
    widgets={'selected_features': pn.widgets.CrossSelector}
))
```

See more documentation on using Param with Panel here: 
https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Param.html