# Panel + Param custom MultiFileSelector widget

Tags: parameters, pane, panel-pyviz

I've tried and failed to convert the  MultiFileSelector Param to into a widget that can be interacted with.
From [this tutorial](https://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Param.html), I have tried the following.

```
class CustomExample(param.Parameterized):
    f = param.MultiFileSelector()

pn.Param(CustomExample.param, widgets={ 'f': pn.widgets.Multiselect})
```

But I get the error,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-bb344c131fb8> in <module>
      5     #select_number = param.Selector(objects=[0, 1, 10, 100])
      6 
----> 7 pn.Param(CustomExample.param, widgets={ 'f': pn.widgets.Multiselect})

AttributeError: module 'panel.widgets' has no attribute 'Multiselect'
```

Any pointers will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [param](https://param.holoviz.org/Reference_Manual/param.html), you have to check which parameter comes closest to what you are looking for in this case param.MultiFileSelector:

```
class CustomExample(param.Parameterized):
    file_selector = param.MultiFileSelector(path='*')

pn.Param(CustomExample.param['file_selector'])
```

**This will show the following multifile selector:**
[image: standard multifile selector with param pyviz]


**If you want to change to a different non-default selector, you can do that like this:**

```
class CustomExample(param.Parameterized):
    file_selector = param.MultiFileSelector(path='*')

pn.Param(
    CustomExample.param['file_selector'], 
    widgets={'file_selector': pn.widgets.CrossSelector},
))
```

**Resulting selector:**
[image: overwrite default multi file selector with the panel crosselector]



You already found this documentation:
http://panel.holoviz.org/user_guide/Param.html 

But maybe also have a look at these SO-questions:
[Get a different (non default) widget when using param in parameterized class (holoviz param panel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943569/get-a-different-non-default-widget-when-using-param-in-parameterized-class-ho) 

[What is the best way to change the widget type in an hvplot/holoviews/panel object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54911674/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-the-widget-type-in-an-hvplot-holoviews-panel-obje)

Comment: Thanks @Sander. I checked the suggested links but could not find a way to double click a folder and choose files within that folder. Sort of like a file browser.

Comment: Ah, so you're looking for a selector where you get a file browser AND are able to select multiple files, like this: https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/FileInput.html#gallery-fileinput but then for multiple files. It's best to put your question here, hope they can help your: https://discourse.holoviz.org/

Comment: As suggested, I think the best place to post your question would be here: https://discourse.holoviz.org/